# What are these three different texture types I found in Pokémon sun?

Tags: textures, graphics, blender, uv-mapping

I am currently trying to extract the Pokémon models/textures/animations of the Pokémon Sun game so i can use them as placeholders in Godot.

At the moment I have the model, the textures and the animations in separate files, and now i am trying to put them all together using blender.

Combining the smd model and animation into a dae file works perfectly. The problem that i have right now is that the texture mapping is completely wrong.

After a closer look at the textures it seems like there are two or three files for each texture. One is the texture itself, one is a grey scaled image and the third is a rainbow colored image.

I don't really know much about texture compositions so I was wondering how these files play together.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You realize that you ask us to help you steal work done by other game developers, right?

Comment: why stealing? I wan't to create a game like pokemon and want them as placeholder models.

Comment: Why not use a simple box? Placeholders are designed to take no time to create, you are already wasting time by trying to extract it.

Comment: It's easier to learn what these textures are if you need them on a game you are making vs copy-pasting what others are doing.

Comment: @TomTsagk are you even reading the post? I want to use them as placeholders because they already have animations and so on. So i can implement everything and  at the end i just have to switch out the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should never use assets from someone else's game in your own game, there is a lot you can learn from reverse-engineering the games of other people and figuring out how they did things.

The first texture appears to be an albedo texture. This is a texture which tells you which parts of the object have which basic color. This texture is usually the most important one, and most 3d models should look at least recognizable with just this texture. So this is the one you should focus on first.

The last one (the one with the rainbow colors) seems to be a [normal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) (also known as "bump map"). A normal map tells you the direction in which each pixel faces. It is important for shading an object correctly. Note that it seems to use different UV coordinates than the other two textures (or it could be from an entirely different 3d model).

The second one (the black and white one) could fulfill various effect purposes.

- It could be an [occlusion map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion). An occlusion map is used to add additional darkness to sections of the model. This is a relatively cheap way to add self-shadowing to parts of a 3d model which are virtually always in shade.
- It could be a [height map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap), which makes some parts of a polygon render higher or lower without actually requiring any additional geometry.
- It could be a specular map. A specular map tells you which parts of the model are "shiny" and which are "dull". (considering that it matches the albedo texture very well, this seems to be the most likely)